# WPF correct way to set a bool while a key is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, keyboard

I WPF I need to set a boolean variable (and additionally perform some other actions) while a key is pressed. I.e. to set on the key is pressed, and to reset on the key is released. Something that I can do by just event handlers:

```
this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(MyModuleView_KeyDown);
this.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(MyModuleView_KeyUp);

bool MyFlag = false;

void MyModuleView_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Space)
        {
            MyFlag = false;
            ...
        }

    }

    void MyModuleView_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Space)
        {
            MyFlag = true;
            ...
        }
    }
```

But I suspect in WPF it can be done in a more correct way.
I'm trying to use a command approach, but in the way I do it I can only set a variable **on the fact** of pressing a key but not **while** a key is pressed.:

```
private static RoutedUICommand mymode;

InputGestureCollection inputs = new InputGestureCollection();
        inputs.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.Space, "Space"));
        mymode = new RoutedUICommand("MyMode", "MyMode", typeof(InterfaceCommands), inputs);
public static RoutedUICommand MyMode
{
    get { return mymode; }
}
...
private void MyModeCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyFlag = true;
    ...
}
```

How to correctly track the state of a key in WPF for turning on something (for example selection mode of a cursor) **while** the key is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commands will not help you here, your approach with events is a right way to go. If you don't like to have a code-behind - you can create a custom attached property, which would be responsible for events wiring.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [AttachedCommandBehavior library](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/) and examples provided